# I want to put the first done transition date in a custom field of already done issues from JIRA using Jira api and scripts

Tags: javascript, node.js, ruby-on-rails, jira-rest-api

Assume that this is the changelog of a Jira issue

```json
{
    "expand": "renderedFields,names,schema,operations,editmeta,changelog,versionedRepresentations",
    "id": "72194",
    "self": "https://jira.instance.net/rest/api/2/issue/72194",
    "key": "TII-627",
    "changelog": {
        "startAt": 0,
        "maxResults": 1,
        "total": 1,
        "histories": [
            {
                "id": "12345",
                "author": {
                    "self": "https://jira.instance.net/rest/api/2/user?accountId=xxxxxxxxxxx",
                    "accountId": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                    "emailAddress": "xxx@yy.com",
                    "avatarUrls": {},
                    "displayName": "John Doe",
                    "active": true,
                    "timeZone": "Anywhere",
                    "accountType": "atlassian"
                },
                "created": "2023-02-07T10:30:02.897+0530",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "field": "status",
                        "fieldtype": "jira",
                        "fieldId": "status",
                        "from": "10000",
                        "fromString": "To Do",
                        "to": "5",
                        "toString": "Resolved"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "fields": {
        "status": {
            "self": "https://jira.instance.net/rest/api/2/status/5",
            "description": "A resolution has been taken, and it is awaiting verification by reporter. From here issues are either reopened, or are closed.",
            "iconUrl": "something",
            "name": "Resolved",
            "id": "5",
            "statusCategory": {
                "self": "https://jira.instance.net/rest/api/2/statuscategory/3",
                "id": 3,
                "key": "done",
                "colorName": "green",
                "name": "Done"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this changelog you can see that the issue with "key": "TII-627" was first transition to done statuscategory aka Resolved status on "created": "2023-02-07T10:30:02.897+0530"

I want to get this first transition to done and print it in a table for all issues in the project like this

issue_key, first_resolved_at

for the eg. above it would look like this

TII-627, 2023-02-07T10:30:02.897+0530

I have tried using the following ruby script but I am getting the first resolved date empty please let me know what can I do

```
require 'jira-ruby'

# JIRA API credentials
jira_username = '<your-jira-username>'
jira_token = '<your-jira-api-token>'
jira_domain = '<your-jira-instance-domain>'

# initialize client
options = {
    :username => jira_username,
    :password => jira_token,
    :site => "https://#{jira_domain}",
    :context_path => '',
    :auth_type => :basic
}
client = JIRA::Client.new(options)

# Define the issue key as a command line argument
issue_key = ARGV[0]

# Log the start time of the script
start_time = Time.now
puts "Start time: #{start_time}"

# Get the issue information
begin
  issue = client.Issue.find(issue_key)
  issue_status_category = issue.fields['status']['statusCategory']['name']

 # If issue has already reached done status, retrieve the transitions
  if issue_status_category == 'Done'
    transitions = issue.transitions
    first_resolved_at = nil
    last_resolved_at = nil

    # Retrieve the first and last resolved dates
    transitions.each do |transition|
      transition_status_category = transition['to']['statusCategory']['name']
      if transition_status_category == 'Done'
        transition_created_at = DateTime.parse(transition['created'])
        if first_resolved_at.nil?
          first_resolved_at = transition_created_at
        end
        last_resolved_at = transition_created_at
      end
    end

    # Print the results
    puts "Issue Key: #{issue.key}"
    puts "First Resolved At: #{first_resolved_at}"
    puts "Last Resolved At: #{last_resolved_at}"
  else
    puts "Issue has not yet reached Done status."
  end
rescue Exception => e
  # Log the error
  puts "Error: #{e}"
end

# Log the end time of the script
end_time = Time.now
puts "End time: #{end_time}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am closing the question. I was able to figure out another way using JS

```
const axios = require("axios");
​
async function getFirstResolvedDate(jiraUsername, jiraToken, jiraDomain, issues) {
  for (const issue of issues) {
    let changelogs = [];
    let url = jiraDomain + "/rest/api/2/issue/" + issue + "?expand=changelog";
    let response = await axios({
      method: "get",
      url: url,
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic " + Buffer.from(jiraUsername + ":" + jiraToken).toString("base64"),
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      }
    });
    let data = response.data;
    let changelog = data.changelog.histories;
    if (!Array.isArray(changelog)) {
      changelog = [changelog];
    }
    for (const history of changelog) {
      let items = history.items;
      for (const item of items) {
        if (item.field === "status" && (item.toString === "Resolved" || item.toString === "Invalid")) {
          let firstResolvedAt = history.created;
          changelogs.push({
            issue_key: issue,
            first_resolved_at: firstResolvedAt
          });
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    let earliestDate = new Date(Math.min.apply(null, changelogs.map(function(c) {
      return new Date(c.first_resolved_at);
    })));
    let formattedDate = earliestDate.toISOString();
    url = jiraDomain + "/rest/api/2/issue/" + issue;
    let body = {
      fields: {
        customfield_xxx: formattedDate
      }
    };
    response = await axios({
      method: "put",
      url: url,
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic " + Buffer.from(jiraUsername + ":" + jiraToken).toString("base64"),
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      data: body
    });
    if (response.status === 200 || response.status === 204) {
      console.log("Successfully updated first resolved date for issue " + issue);
    } else {
      console.error(response);
    }
  }
}
​
const jiraUsername = 'xxx';
const jiraToken = "xxx";
const jiraDomain = "https://xxx";
const issues = ['xxx-1'];
​
getFirstResolvedDate(jiraUsername, jiraToken, jiraDomain, issues)
  .then(result => {
    console.log(result);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```